# Method name expected error in c#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a list where every row has its own delete button.

```
private Button createDeleteButton()
{
    int rowToDelete = ctr;
    Button deleteBtn = new Button();
    deleteBtn.Text = "x";
    deleteBtn.Click += new EventHandler(RemoveRow(rowToDelete));
    return deleteBtn;
}


protected void RemoveRow(int specificRow)
{

    TableRow rw = table.Rows[specificRow];
    table.Rows.Remove(rw);

    ctr--;

    Session["table"] = table;
    ViewState["ctr"] = ctr;

}
```

However, I get the error "method not defined" on RemoveRow(rowToDelete) in

```
    deleteBtn.Click += new EventHandler(RemoveRow(rowToDelete));
```

any thoughts?

Comment: Please **do not** modify your question to ask something completely different. This will invalidate all answers people have given you, wasting all the effort they took to help you. Instead, ask another question.

Answer (score 1):

this will do the trick for you.

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int rowToDelete = 1;
        Button deleteBtn = new Button();
        deleteBtn.Text = "x";
        deleteBtn.Click += (snd, evtargs) => { RemoveRow(snd, evtargs, rowToDelete); };
    }

    private void RemoveRow(object sender, EventArgs e, int index)
    {
        //your code
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a closure to capture your `rowToDelete` variable.

```
deleteBtn.Click += (s, e) => RemoveRow(rowToDelete);
```

But be warned, that this might lead to a memory leak, because you don't unsubscribe from an event.

Comment: It solves the error, but the method is (for some reason) never called this way